# Possibility of detecting MAC address spoofing in Ethereum network?

Tags: network, networking

The paper that has been published here: https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=3282283 proposes a consensus algorithm based on distributed voting process as an alternative to proof-of-work based blockchains, in which it claims that it would be possible to **detect and recognize (and not prevent)** MAC address change using **Cisco Port Security** in a crypto-currency network, because this proposed idea is based on **one-machine-one-vote** and so it is important to **recognize** MAC address change in the network.

Do you think it is practicable to **recognize (and not prevent)** MAC address change in a blockchain network ?

I mean assuming a node is connected to a blockchain network like Ethereum network, then if this node changes its MAC address, is it possible to notify the rest of Ethereum network, **if Ethereum network uses Cisco Port Security configuration for detecting MAC address change?**

Is "**fingerprinting a node**" can be considered as a solution to detect MAC address spoofing in Ethereum network without sacrificing "decentralization of Ethereum"? (https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fingerprint) or (https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d5ef/30919b4f28b82d6fb637e17a5a992f82ecaa.pdf)

Thank you

P.S. MAC address change detection using Cisco Port Security is described here: https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst4000/8-2glx/configuration/guide/sec_port.pdf and here: https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/sw/4_1/nx-os/security/configuration/guide/sec_nx-os-cfg/sec_portsec.pdf